# Injecting service into a mixin Ember2.3+

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit

I am having a problem with an error that pops up in my unit test suite when I try to check **a service injected into Mixin** since `getOwner()` has been added into Ember (deprecation guide [here](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/#toc_deprecations-added-in-2-3)).

This is my mixin:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    sha: Ember.inject.service('sha512'),
});
```

This is my basic unit test slightly changed after being generated by ember-cli:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DirtyRelationshipsDetectorMixin from 'xamoom-customer/mixins/dirty-relationships-detector';
import { module, test } from 'qunit';

module('Unit | Mixin | dirty relationships detector');

test('it works', function(assert) {
  let DirtyRelationshipsDetectorObject = Ember.Object.extend(DirtyRelationshipsDetectorMixin);
  let subject = DirtyRelationshipsDetectorObject.create();
  assert.ok(subject);
  assert.ok(subject.get('sha')); // problem occurs here
});
```

The error message I am getting is quite clear but I haven't found a solution:

> Error: Assertion Failed: Attempting to lookup an injected property on
>   an object without a container, ensure that the object was instantiated
>   via a container.

The service is there when the app is running, it's just the test that fails.
**Ember 2.5.1 - Ember-CLI 2.5.0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Ember.getOwner(target)` you can not just `.create()` the target, but [inject the owner.](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/ContainerProxyMixin.html#method_ownerInjection) with `.create(owner.ownerInjection())`. Typically an owner is an app instance.

**Edit:**

You are actually using `getOwner` when you use `Ember.inject`. Its like a shortcut for this:

```
sha: Ember.computed({
  get() {
    return Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('service:sha');
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not using Ember.getOwner() at all as you can see.
I tried to change create() to: `let subject = DirtyRelationshipsDetectorObject.create(Ember.getOwner(this).ownerInjection());` but it fails of course since `this` is not an app instance.

Comment: I edited the Answer. Its a unit test, so what do you think *should* happen if you use the service?

Comment: Alright, makes sense now as you explained the shortcut thing. Do I get it well - I should not test this property explicitly and mock it (later in my tests suits) instead?

Comment: Depends highly on your use case. Probably you mock it, if you don't mock it you need to include the full service, but then you are on integration tests I guess.